# "error: 'value' redeclared as different kind of symbol" Even though it's never been redeclared

Tags: c

Doing an assignment to make a tic-tac-toe game, and this early I've hit a block.

Compilers keeps hollering at me that my array has been redeclared as a different kind of symbol even though it's been declared as nothing but an array.

As I am learning I hope this is an obvious fix.

```
    char board[4][4];
    printf("Would you like to play a game of tic-tac-toe? (Y or N)\n");
    scanf("%c", &start);
    while(start!=N && start!=n){
        void clearField(char board[4][4]);
        void printField(char board[4][4]);
    }
}
void clearField(char board[4][4]){
    char board[4][4]={{ ,0,1,2},{0,_,_,_},{1,_,_,_},{2,_,_,_}};
}
```

Error is at the second to last line. "board redeclared as different kind of symbol". What gives?

Comment: In `clearField` you have a local var with same name as the parameter.

Comment: Also, in the `while`, you are not calling the functions, just declaring them. You want `clearField(board); printField(board);`

Comment: Also, your arrays should be chars: `'1', '2',` etc.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Don't I have to include the local var in the parameter? Isn't that how you import stuff from function to function without using global variables?

Comment: If you pass `board` as a parameter, you don't have to redeclare it. `void clearField(char board[4][4]) {board[0][0] = ' '; board[0][1] = '0'; .....}`

Comment: Note that the `while` loop just declares two functions (`void clearField(char board[4][4]); void printField(char board[4][4]);`) — it does not call them (`clearField(board); printField(board);` would call them). The absence of a number or other symbol before the first comma in `char board[4][4]={{ ,0,1,2}…` is wrong, too.  Since the code shown isn't an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses; MCVE was good for over five years and it did not need changing), it's hard to know why the compiler's complaining.

Comment: why do you say you are not redeclaring when you are continously redeclaring things? you are declaring `char board[4][4]` as a parameter to function `clearField` and then again later in the body of the function as a local variable... each time you begin something with a type identifier **you are declaring something**.  Indeed, you are not calling your functions, but just declaring them.

Answer (score 2):

Inside `clearField()`, you are indeed re-declaring the array with the same name as the argument, which makes no sense.

If you intended to assign to the argument, which makes sense, you can't repeat it's type like that.

Also, you cannot assign to arrays like that, most normal code would use either nested loops or a `memset()` call, I think.

Other strangenesses include the non-quoted `N` and `n` that you compare `start` against, and the repeated pointless function declarations inside the `if`.

It seems you really need to read up on basic C syntax and structure, you seem to want to repeat declarations when you actually need statements that do something (like calling a function).